# mysql grouping distinct query

Tags: mysql, oracle, distinct, grouping

I have the following data in my database table, since I'm fairly new to MYSQL i'm having problems in querying it to give me the following output

```
   City      Subject
   london    english  
   toronto   math     
   london    math     
   london    math     
   toronto   english  
   toronto   english
```

There can only be two subjects, english or math. Im trying to output the data this way, first the query should pick all the distinct items in the city column. Then tell me the count of each subject in that city.

output

```
  city     English  Math
  london   1        2
  toronto  2        1
```

I tried grouping, but since I don't know mysql that well, I realized it just groups the subjects together and eats the cities while grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT city,
  SUM(IF(subject='english',1,0)) AS English,
  SUM(IF(subject='math',1,0)) AS Math
FROM foo
GROUP BY city;
```

Comment: Thank you. Just curious, the statement means if subject is english in a row, add one to the sum, if not then add 0 right? Where can I read more about such functions.

Comment: Sort of... Run this without out the GROUPing to get a better understanding:  `SELECT *,IF(subject='english',1,0) AS English,IF(subject='math',1,0) AS Math FROM foo`.  See how the columns become counters.  Then we just SUM the counters. Google 'mysql aggregate functions' and use the mysql website